# Preventing SystemUI from automatically restarting

Tags: android

I am developing an app that requires that the SystemUI to be completely gone, no Navigation Bar and no Status Bar. Immersive Mode is not enough, since the Navigation Bar will still pop up if the user swipes up at the bottom of the screen.

After a lot of research, I have found some snippets that don't work anymore since they're from ~2011. What I have managed to do is kill the SystemUI through `pkill -9 com.android.systemui` but it restarts by itself a few seconds later. So the perfect solution seems to be *to prevent the UI from restarting*, then manually restarting it when needed. All of this just so the device doesn't need a reboot. Is that possible at all?

Another solution would be to "freeze" the SystemUI, in such a way that it does not respond to the user trying to pull the Navigation Bar back up, but I have found absolutely nothing on that matter.

Obviously, the device is rooted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @DamianHelme not exactly. The only way I have found to completely disable the SystemUI involved rebooting the device, but in that case, in order to re-enable it, it would be required to reboot the device once again. Apparently this is doable in older versions of Android but is no longer allowed. I hope it becomes doable again in future flavours.

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand you need the UI to be unused.
Therefore you can try to disable the UI with the command after connecting the device via ADB:

```
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.android.systemui
```

This can only be reachable on rooted devices